# What to replace a rear Shimano RSX derailleur with?

Tags: shimano, derailleur

I have a Shimano RSX 8 speed rear derailleur and on a 20year old bike. It starts to play up and I would like to replace it. Since the RSX-Series is not produced any more, I was wondering with which model I could replace my old derailleur? Thanks everybody!

Comment: You might want to go to your local bike shop and see what they have in their bins.

Comment: Are you sure the derailleur is the problem? Usually derailleurs will last a long time (if they don’t get smashed and bent). It’s the cables and cable housing which need occasional replacement.

Answer (score 3):

There's a number that would work. The first thing is to determine whether it's long or short cage (GS vs SS respectively in Shimano parlance). If you want something currently made that's a decent replacement of around the same quality, the Sora RD-R3000-SS or -GS is closest. It's nominally 9-speed but will work. For cheaper the current Claris R2000 will also work. If you wanted to get something nice for a bike you want to keep going indefinitely, RD-5701 would be good and is still made.